# Importing Locally Installed Node Modules in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

**Scenario:**

I'm developing a script using TypeScript (version >= 3). My script has features which dependend upon a well-known graphics library, which itself is written in JavaScript. I have installed this library and its TypeScript type definitions locally in my project, resulting in the relevant files being placed in the appropriate sub-directories of the "node_modules" directory.

I have my project set up to transpile my TypeScript to **ES6**-specification JavaScript.

I have an import statement at the top of my main TypeScript file of the form:

```
import * as LIB from 'library'
```

Where "library.js" is the required library file, burried somewhere in the sub-directories of "node_modules". The TypeScript compiler has its own complex process of [module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) which means that it can find this file without requiring a relative filepath or a file extension.

If I run the TypeScript compiler on my main ".ts" file, I get a JavaScript file out. Because I'm using ES6, the import statement in the generated JavaScript file is **identical to the one in my TypeScript source**. This is my issue.

The file that the generated JavaScript is attempting to import cannot be found by the script when it runs on my local development server, because the file it is trying to import is somewhere inside the "node_modules" directory and the import is not pointing to that directory. As such, an error along the lines of `Error resolving module specifier` is shown in the browser console when the code is executed.

**I want the code to transpile from TypeScript to JavaScript (ES6) in such a way that the imports in the generated JavaScript can be resolved when I serve my code to a browser from a local test server.**

**Question:**

1) Is this behaviour a result of my improperly configuring the TypeScript compiler?

2) Is this behaviour something that results from or is influenced in a direct way by the properties in the "tsconfig.json" and/or "package.json" configuration files?

3) Is this actually a problem, or is it all caused by my not understanding how files should be organised and served from a Node server?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It should work just fine but avoid `*` imports unless the library is shipped as ESM. Anyway it is easy to test the issue. 1: `> node` 2: `var lib = require("library"); console.table(lib);`

Answer (score 0):

While you say you are running the code "on a node-based server", your error message suggests that you are actually serving an ES6 module containing a non-relative import like `import * as LIB from 'library'` to a browser.  As you suggest, that isn't supported because the resolution algorithm for non-relative imports in browsers hasn't been standardized yet; see, for example, [this article](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/#bare-import-specifiers-arent-currently-supported).  Either you would need a separate tool to rewrite the non-relative import to a relative import (I'm not familiar with such tools but would invite others to describe them in other answers) or you would need to switch from browser native modules to a non-native [module bundler or loader](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+module+(bundler+OR+loader)+for+browser) such as Webpack, Rollup, Browserify, or RequireJS, any of which should support your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You were correct to say that I am serving an ES6 module to a browser, not running it on the server. I've edited my question to clarify this. Thanks also for your suggestions regarding bundlers and loaders. Ideally though, I was trying to use as few extra tools in my workflow as possible.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, it looks like my problem cannot be solved (in a general way) without using a module bundler or loader as suggested by @Matt McCutchen. Here's a couple of discussions of the issue on the TypeScript GitHub page: [1](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577), [2](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26722).

For others finding this question in future, I solved the problem in my specific case a very unsatisfactory way - by avoiding using imports at all, and simply loading the requied library in a HTML script tag before I loaded my main dependent script. This is only acceptable because my project has a single dependency which will not be updated (so I won't ever have to change the "src" in the script tag manually).

I emphasise again, this is not a satisfactory solution in the general case, so I will leave the question open for a while in case anyone comes up with a better answer.